# NullPointerException when downloading a Image

Tags: android, android-image

Until now, I had this code in one of my fragments:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.foto_setmana, container, false); //Això conté els "edittext i altres"
    cont=getActivity(); //Recupero el contexte per poder pasar-lo.

    try {
        new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).execute("http://192.168.1.36/testing/fotos/foto1.jpg");
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("errors", "Wohoops. Crashed");
    }

    return myFragmentView;
}
```

But because of swipping between fragments, it's constantly loading this image each time I go back to that fragment, I decided to move the code, to the main FragmentActivity. Also I've read that it's a good practice to don't use any code like this inside a fragment.

I've tried this:

```
public class AndroidViewPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {
[...]
try {
        Log.d("debugging","a");
        new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).execute("http://192.168.1.36/testing/fotos/foto1.jpg");
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("errors", "Wohoops. Crashed");
    }
}
```

But it's crashing.

There it's the log:

```
01-09 21:37:11.264: E/AndroidRuntime(976): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

01-09 21:37:11.264: E/AndroidRuntime(976): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 21:37:11.264: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at com.exercise.AndroidViewPager.DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(DownloadImageTask.java:34)
01-09 21:37:11.264: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at com.exercise.AndroidViewPager.DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(DownloadImageTask.java:1)
01-09 21:37:11.264: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
01-09 21:37:11.264: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-09 21:37:11.264: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
01-09 21:37:11.264: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 21:37:11.264: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 21:37:11.264: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-09 21:37:11.264: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 21:37:11.264: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-09 21:37:11.264: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-09 21:37:11.264: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-09 21:37:11.264: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As you can see, it's crashing in the Class I was using before (and it worked), when it was called from my fragment.

This is the class code, incase you want to check it:

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage;

public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
    this.bmImage = bmImage;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    Log.d("debugging","b");
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    Log.d("debugging","c");
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}
```

}

The logcat, refers to the last line, exactly:

```
bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
```

Any tips?

Thanks.

**Editing. This way I'm navigating through fragments**

```
public class AndroidViewPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {
ViewPager mViewPager;
TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;
ImageView imatgeSetmana;
Bitmap fotoSetmanaBitmap;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
    setContentView(mViewPager);

    final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
    bar.hide();

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Foto setmana"), MyFragmentA.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Entries this week"), MyFragmentB.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Nothing yet"), MyFragmentC.class, null);

    try {
        //Descarrego la foto
        new DownloadImageTask(this.imatgeSetmana).execute("http://192.168.1.36/testing/fotos/foto1.jpg");
        //Guardo el bitmap de la foto 
        this.fotoSetmanaBitmap=((BitmapDrawable)imatgeSetmana.getDrawable()).getBitmap();


    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("errors", "Wohoops. Crashed");
    }

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you moved the code to your Activity you forgot that `findViewById()` cannot locate a View that is not *currently* visible. `R.id.imageView1` is in the layout that you use in the Fragment, not your Activity. So `findViewById()` returns `null`...
Simply save a reference to the Bitmap in your Activity but only try to display it in your Fragment (when the ImageView is visible.)

---

**Addition**
Since `fotoSetmanaBitmap` is not private you can save it in DownloadImageTask like so:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    Log.d("debugging","c");
    activity.fotoSetmanaBitmap = result; // Where activity is an instance of AndroidViewPagerActivity
}
```

Then load it without using Intents:

```
cont= (AndroidViewPagerActivity) getActivity(); //Recupero el contexte per poder pasar-lo.
if(cont.fotoSetmanaBitmap != null) {
    ImageView image = (ImageView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    image.setImageBitmap(cont.fotoSetmanaBitmap);
}
```

Comment: Sounds totally logic. So how can I pass the image to the fragment so I can load it when its created? I saved the image into the FragmentsActivity like this: `ImageView imatgeSetmana; new DownloadImageTask(this.imatgeSetmana).execute("http://192.168.1.36/testing/fotos/foto1.jpg");`

Comment: Change `DownloadImageTask` to return a Bitmap. When you create the Fragment pass this Bitmap with `intent.putExtra("Bitmap", bitmap);`. Finally in `onCreateView()` read the Bitmap with `intent.getParcelableExtra("Bitmap");` and only then call `setImageBitmap()`.

Comment: Well, my code is a bit weird, as I'm not using intents to call a fragment, im doing it with tabs. I edited my post so you can see how I instance those fragments.

Comment: Anyways, if you find any another workaround, it would be great too. Basically my issue is that I'm implementing this because it's downloading the image again and again when I leave the fragment and go back to it.

Comment: I updated my answer, while it is not perfect, you should be able to build off of it.